# I get the response /root/gcc-4.8.2/bin: No such file or directory when I set the path in bash.rc

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, path, gcc

I already had gcc 4.4.7 in my system. My system is RHEL 6.6.

```
[root@gksrv Desktop]# gcc --version
    gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
    Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I want to upgrade to gcc-4.8.2 and I went through all the steps for installing it on my system.

The final portion of the output I got after typing `make install` is as follows:

```
 Libraries have been installed in:
       /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64

    If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
    in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
    specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
    flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
         during execution
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
         during linking
       - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
       - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

    See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
    more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    test -z "/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info" || /bin/mkdir -p "/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info"
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/Downloads/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/libgomp/libgomp.info '/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info'
     install-info --info-dir='/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info' '/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info/libgomp.info'
    test -z "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/finclude" || /bin/mkdir -p "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/finclude"
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 omp_lib.h omp_lib.f90 omp_lib.mod omp_lib_kinds.mod '/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/finclude'
    test -z "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include"
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 omp.h '/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/include'
    make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgomp'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgomp'
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgomp'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm'
    Making install in testsuite
    make[3]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm/testsuite'
    make[4]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm/testsuite'
    make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
    make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
    make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm/testsuite'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm/testsuite'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm'
    true  DO=all multi-do # make
    make[4]: Entering directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm'
    true  DO=install multi-do # make
    test -z "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64" || /bin/mkdir -p "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64"
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libitm.spec '/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64'
    test -z "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64" || /bin/mkdir -p "/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64"
     /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libitm.la '/root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64'
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libitm.so.1.0.0 /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64/libitm.so.1.0.0
    libtool: install: (cd /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64 && { ln -s -f libitm.so.1.0.0 libitm.so.1 || { rm -f libitm.so.1 && ln -s libitm.so.1.0.0 libitm.so.1; }; })
    libtool: install: (cd /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64 && { ln -s -f libitm.so.1.0.0 libitm.so || { rm -f libitm.so && ln -s libitm.so.1.0.0 libitm.so; }; })
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libitm.lai /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64/libitm.la
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libitm.a /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64/libitm.a
    libtool: install: chmod 644 /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64/libitm.a
    libtool: install: ranlib /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64/libitm.a
    libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/root/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64
    ldconfig: /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Libraries have been installed in:
       /root/gcc-4.8.2/lib/../lib64

    If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
    in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
    specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
    flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
         during execution
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
         during linking
       - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
       - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

    See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
    more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    test -z "/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info" || /bin/mkdir -p "/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info"
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/Downloads/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/libitm/libitm.info '/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info'
     install-info --info-dir='/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info' '/root/gcc-4.8.2/share/info/libitm.info'
    make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm'
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libitm'
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/objdir'
```

However, after typing gcc -v I found that the compiler did not get replaced:

```
 [root@gksrv objdir]# gcc -v
    Using built-in specs.
    Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
    Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)
```

I tried to set the path as root. I typed `vim .bashrc` and I arrived at this window:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

if [ -d "/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/bin:$PATH"
fi

export ALTERAOCLSDKROOT="/home/altera/15.0/hld"

export QSYS_ROOTDIR="/home/altera/15.0/quartus/sopc_builder/bin"

PATH= /root/gcc-4.8.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

As one can see above, I added the path to this script in the following way:

```
PATH= /root/gcc-4.8.2/bin:$PATH
    export PATH
```

After I type `echo $PATH` I get the following response:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/root/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin
```

The path for gcc-4.8.2 has clearly not been detected.

**How can I set the PATH so that `gcc-4.8.2` is recognized as the default compiler and not `gcc-4.4.7`?**

EDIT:

I followed the boxama's advice and my path got updated:

```
/root/gcc-4.8.2/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-1.b13.el6.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/root/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin
```

I get the following output now after typing `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/gcc-4.8.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /root/Downloads/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=/root/gcc-4.8.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

Comment: Paste your `.bashrc` there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a space after `PATH=`, and should surround the value with `"` marks so that `$PATH` can properly be replaced:

```
export PATH="/root/gcc-4.8.2/bin:$PATH"
```

Also, make sure to reload your .bashrc so that your changes actually apply:

```
# source /root/.bashrc
```

Prepending the path to the newer gcc before /usr/bin will allow it to take precedence over the older installation.

Note that since gcc has been installed into /root no other users will be able to access/run it.

Comment: I followed your answer and now my path has been updated. I see gcc-4.8.2 when I type `gcc -v`.

Answer (score 0):

gcc-4.9.2 is available from the repo´s : # `yum install centos-release-scl-rh`

```
# yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
```

Enabling gcc / g++ version 4.9.2 : $ `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash`

Answer (score 0):

gcc-4.9.2 is available from the repo´s : # `yum install centos-release-scl-rh`

```
# yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
```

Enabling gcc / g++ version 4.9.2 : $ `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash`

---

Available from http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2 is **gcc-4.8.2** → → → https://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo

```
# yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-c++
```

Enabling 4.8.2 : $ `scl enable devtoolset-2 bash`

Comment: What other benefits would I have after installing 4.9.2?